# JavaScript Blockly.FieldDropdown parameters

Tags: javascript, parameters, blockly

I'm doing a project with [**blockly**](https://developers.google.com/blockly/) which is a javascript library, i can't understand what type of parameters does the menuGenerator variable of the **Blockly.FieldDropdown** function accept.
Here you can see the bit of code interested:

```
/**
* Class for an editable dropdown field.
* @param {(!Array.<!Array>|!Function)} menuGenerator An array of options
*     for a dropdown list, or a function which generates these options.
* @param {Function=} opt_validator A function that is executed when a new
*     option is selected, with the newly selected value as i ts sole 
argument.
*     If it returns a value, that value (which must be one of the options) 
will
*     become selected in place of the newly selected option, unless the 
return
*     value is null, in which case the change is aborted.
* @extends {Blockly.Field}
* @constructor
*/
Blockly.FieldDropdown = function(menuGenerator, opt_validator) {
```

i can't understand what does *@param {(!Array.|!Function)}* mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/blockly/guides/create-custom-blocks/dropdown-menus) has more information and examples, including the basic structure of the dropdown options and how to make a [dynamic dropdown menu](https://developers.google.com/blockly/guides/create-custom-blocks/dropdown-menus#dynamic_menu).

The basic structure is:

> Each dropdown menu is created with a list of menu options. Each option
>   is made up of two strings. The first is the human-readable text to
>   display. The second is a string constant which is used when saving the
>   option to XML. This separation allows a dropdown menu's setting to be
>   preserved between languages. For instance an English version of a
>   block may define `[['left', 'LEFT'], ['right', 'RIGHT']]` while a German
>   version of the same block would define 
>   `[['links', 'LEFT'], ['rechts', 'RIGHT']]`.

And for a dynamic menu:

> Instead of providing a static list of options, one can provide a
>   function that returns a list of options when called. Every time the
>   menu is opened, the function is called and the options are
>   recalculated.

If `menuGenerator` is an array it is used; if it's a function it is run when the menu is opened.  The function does not take in any arguments; it returns a list of options, structured as described above.